# Thread pool and data affinity

Tags: c++, multithreading, pool

I am designing an OMS and trying to use multi-threading techniques to speed up processing.

An easy way is to allocate threads statically: one thread for all securities starting with a letter.  Obviously some of them could be very busy while others have nothing to do. And we don't know in advance what stocks users will enter.

So I turn to thread pool. Now time is likely to be distributed more evenly among threads. But there is an overhead to be dealt with: I have to lock each order, which certainly is not pleasant.

Any idea about how to minimize lock time and achieve higher throughput?

Thanks a lot for suggestions.

P.S, it'a Unix environment. Language used is C++

Answer (score 0):

Generally, thread per task is very bad decision. The best way is separating tasks into logical groups with own thread pools (or, may be with 1 thread per task). Also you should organize communication between tasks for example by queries.
Do you looking throw existed thread pool implementations like [threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Alex,
Seems to me all threadpool implementations do not consider data affinity. So if I use a threadpool, lot of locks/notifications are necessary to ensure data integrity. 
Are you aware of any implementations of threadpool that take data affinity into consideration? Ideally I don't want any lock in my code. All events for an order shall be processed sequentially.

Thanks
Pat

Comment: "all threadpool implementations do not consider data affinity" - yes. "if I use a threadpool, lot of locks/notifications are necessary to ensure data integrity" - no. basically, you have to add locks/notifications for providing atomic add/remove query operation, of case just in case of using queues for communications. I suppose you would better to look throw ACE (cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) tutorial, they provide some information regarding thread-pool server creation.